# jQuery doesn't load content of page in Div

Tags: php, jquery

I have this page, terms.php with this content:

```
<label>
    <span>
       <a id="terms" href="/terms.php">Terms</a>
   </span>
       <input type="checkbox" name="terms" /> I Accept 
</label>

<div id="content-area"></div>


 <script>
        jQuery.fn.terms_agree = function(content_area, selector) {
           var body = $(body);

        $(this).click(function() {
          body.css("height", "auto").css("height", body.height()); // Prevent page flicker on slideup
           if ($(content_area).html() == "") {
               $(content_area).load( $(this).attr("href") + (selector ? " " + selector : "") );
       }
        $(content_area).slideToggle();
           return false;
       });
     }

$(function() {
     $("#terms").terms_agree("#content-area");
});
</script>
```

On terms.php i have:

```
 <html>
   <head>
     <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "https://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="https://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  </head>
  <body>
       TEST TEST TEST
  </body>
 </html>
```

When I click on the link "Terms", a div is loaded which is totally blank. I checked the url to terms.php and that is working fine. Also terms.php is showing content when I visit it directly.

What is going wrong?

Comment: So where do you load the JQuery library?

Comment: In the head of the page of the script at the top.
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script> (with https and the slashes before code.jquery.com) but this site filters it.

Comment: Nothing in your browser's DevConsole/Network tab? Any error? `<doctype>` and `<html>` inside a `<head>` element?

Comment: I tested your code with a test URL that returns content and it worked.

Comment: Thanks all, I had to add a CSS item: clear: both before the Div, now it works.